# Limit query result of array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to limit the number of results I get in an array field?
I have an schema like this:

```
{
    timestamp: Number,
    users: [{ name: String, age: Number }]
}
```

I'm using mongoose and I need to limit the results of the `users` field in this example.

Is it possible to do that? I didn't find anything around, just the `limit` for the documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the $slice operator is what you need

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/

```
db.coll.find({timestamp: 1}, {users: {$slice: 10}})
```

Comment: Yes, that's  it! Thanks! In fact I read about it but had misunderstood =/

Comment: Is it possible to get first ten, then next ten and so on.? Something like paginate